# Convert mySQL query into sequelize model query

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have a mySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT restaurant.id, restaurant.name, restaurant.address, restaurant.phone, restaurant.lat, restaurant.lng, restaurant.image, restaurant.payment_url, ROUND(111.045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(30.3298)) * COS(RADIANS(restaurant.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(-81.4860) - RADIANS(restaurant.lng)) + SIN(RADIANS(restaurant.lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(30.3298)))), 2) AS distance_in_km FROM restaurant) AS d WHERE d.distance_in_km < 10
```

I want to convert it into sequelize model query with sequelize model name is `Restaurant`

Comment: Please format your SQL query (you can use https://sqlformat.org/ for instance)

Comment: Please share what you have attempted